# Bogus rendering when <br/> or <br> tags are preceded and followed by newlines

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

Seen at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/34012/3 with Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04,

```
<br/>
text `code` **bold**

more text
```

Renders as:

[image: bogus formatting]

Instead of:

[image: expected formatting]

The generated HTML is:

```
<br/>
text `code` **bold**
<p>more text</p>
```

instead of:

```
<p><br>text <code>code</code> <strong>bold</strong></p>
<p>more text</p>
```

Currently in your browser:

text `code` **bold**

more text

That doesn't happen if the line above the `<br/>` is not blank or there are non-blanks around `<br/>` as in:

```
text
<br/>
test
```

Or

```
<br/>text
```

Example in your browser:

text `code` **bold**

more text

Comment: But why use `<br/>` at all? I think that generally, most markdown is disabled if it has another "command" above it, like `---` requiring an empty line in order for it to be rendered as a horizontal line, but is this a problem? If you just leave an empty line instead of the br tag doesn't it work?

Comment: @terdon, I wouldn't do that myself, I'm just reporting a rendering bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior according to the Commonmark spec ([link against the reference implementation](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%0A%3Cbr%2F%3E%0Atext%20%60code%60%20**bold**%0A%0Amore%20text)).

The `<br/>` constitutes opening an HTML block , which (for most start conditions) is only terminated by `a blank line`. In [the Commonmark reference spec for HTML block](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#html-block), the appropriate condition here is number 7.